# Low accuracy of a Deep CNN

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have generated a dataset using EMNIST and mathematical symbols that has one character per image or two characters per image. There are 72 possible characters in the dataset. The image is sized at 28x56(hxw).

Ex:- [single character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXtWR.png) [double character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xapmy.png)

There are 5256 (72*73) possible classes considering all the combinations of the characters. This is from 72 possible characters in the first part and 73 possible characters(including a blank) in the second part of the label. I have made sure that each class has around 540-600 images. The total dataset has around 3 million images.

The CNN models I have tried:

```
  input_shape = (28, 56, 1)
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False,
  input_shape=input_shape))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Dropout(.2))

  model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Dropout(.2))

  model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', use_bias=False))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Activation('relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Dropout(.3))

  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))

  model.add(Dense(units=5256, activation='softmax'))
  sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

  model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
```

I even tried a model with two Dense layers of 10512 units aswell. I was only able to acheive  an accuracy of around 66%. I have tried various batch sizes from 32,64,256 and ADAM optimizer with various learning rates aswell. It would be great if someone can point out what I am doing wrong here.or give some tips on increasing the accuracy.

Comment: 1) give more details of the process: preprocessing, training params, training log.
2) 66% may be low for simple EMNIST but you deal here with quite many classes.
3) try using one of the pre-trained networks and just re-train last 1-2 layers.
4) look at the confusion matrix. See if certain classes are more difficult to learn correctly.

Comment: The images are in binary format (0,255) and is normalized before feeding into the network. The notebook can be found - Large network -https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WJ1qVpK-VSEfHxwafS_A5KClER6qdleB 
smaller network -https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RI00288XD5WQvuzqbwivagBwMEmbYqWp

Answer (score 0):

On following Ruslan S.'s recommendation, I trained the model on Resnet50(Retrained the whole network, not just last layers). I was able to achieve a significant improvement of Accuracy. I was able to reach around 96% accuracy.